# JavaScript - "implementation-defined object"

Tags: javascript

I am reading "JavaScript: The Definitive Guide, 6th edition", and in section "3.10.3 The Scope Chain" (page 55) it states -

> "If we think of local variables as properties of some kind of
>   **implementation-defined object**, then there is another way to think about variable scope."

Can someone explain what is meant by "**implementation-defined object**"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of an abstract object that is not exposed to us. It's defined by the implementation, and available to the implementation only – "implementation" meaning the JavaScript engine which will be running your code.

For example, consider the following function:

```
function f(a,b) {
    var foo = 5;
    return a + b + foo;
}
```

The variables and arguments defined within that function's scope could be represented as an object that would look like this:

```
{
    a,
    b,
    foo
}
```

The values of the object's properties can change during the execution of the function. If you call the function with `f(1,2)`, for example, the object will look like this as soon as the function execution starts:

```
{
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    foo: undefined
}
```

After `foo` is assigned `5`, it will look like this:

```
{
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    foo: 5
}
```

Consider this object as if it was declared inside the function. So, you can access the values of `a`, `b` and `foo` inside the function, but not outside it.

Comment: This is a layman's terms explanation of the sentence you quoted. For a technical explanation based on the language specification, please refer to [James Allardice's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14340190/825789).

Comment: James's answer was WAY above my head, bfavaretto. Thank you very much for your "layman's" answer. My vote goes to you!

Comment: @ABogus No problem! I hope my answer helps you understand James's, and the specification, if you decide to dive deeper into them later. Also, my last 2 examples are intended to tip you about how "variable hoisting" works :).

Answer (score 3):

Local variables are internally represented as bindings to the lexical environment, as shown by the spec ([ES5 10.5](http://es5.github.com/#x10.5) - note that "env" in the following quote refers to the lexical environment of the current scope):

> - For each *VariableDeclaration* and *VariableDeclarationNoIn d* in *code*, in source text order do
>
>   - Let *dn* be the *Identifier* in *d*.
>   - Let *varAlreadyDeclared* be the result of calling *env’s* HasBinding concrete method passing *dn* as the argument.
>   - If *varAlreadyDeclared* is false, then
>
>     - Call *env’s* CreateMutableBinding concrete method passing *dn* and *configurableBindings* as the arguments.
>     - Call *env’s* SetMutableBinding concrete method passing *dn*, undefined, and *strict* as the arguments.

Since you have no programmatic access to the lexical environment of a scope, you can't see these bindings. But it means you can think of local variables as being properties of this invisible object, just as global variables become properties of the global object (which you *can* access).

This concept is summarised nicely at the start of the section quoted from above:

> Every execution context has an associated VariableEnvironment. Variables and functions declared in ECMAScript code evaluated in an execution context are added as bindings in that VariableEnvironment’s Environment Record.

To understand the process in more detail, have a look at the [specification of the `CreateMutuableBinding` and `setMutableBinding`](http://es5.github.com/#x10.2.1) methods.

To answer your actual question, in this case, the "implementation-defined object" is the lexical environment of the current execution context.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, James. But, I _am_ just a layman, and I have NO FREAKING IDEA what you are talking about! But... I will make it my life mission to try to understand your it! Thanks!

Comment: @ABogus - No problem, hopefully in the future you'll be able to understand it. If you can stick with it, the spec is a great learning tool, but it does take a bit of effort to get through!

Comment: BTW - I meant to say "I will make it my life mission to try to understand **it**!"